# How do I seperate street names and house numbers with PHP?

Tags: php, regex

In Germany we have street names and house numbers. I work with a database where both is stored in a single column (for example "Arnoldstraße 12") and I want to seperate both into single variables.

I have this code:

---

```
$street= $row[2]; //This row is from an array with values of the database. The other rows are submitted perfectly.
preg_match('/([^\d]+)(\d+.*)/', $street, $matches);
$street_new = trim($matches[1]);
$house_number= trim($matches[2]);  

while ($row = $jobDB->fetchArray($result)) {
        $this->setReturnValue('strasse', $street_new);
        $this->setReturnValue('hausnummer', $house_number);
        return;
    }
```

---

After that, I use a JS-Code to get that (and more values) into a form on a website. The other values get there without problems, just the street name and the house number are missing.

Here's the JS-code:

---

```
var auto_complete = function() { 
    var kontonr = jr_get_value('tb_kundennummer');
    jr_execute_dialog_function('autoComplete', {kontonummer: kontonr}, mySuccessCallback);    
}

var mySuccessCallback = function(returnObject) {
    jr_set_value('tb_kunde_strasse', returnObject.result.street_new); 
    jr_set_value('tb_kunde_hausnummer', returnObject.result.house_number);
}
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Can you show what's inside `$street`?

Comment: It's a string like "Arnoldstraße 12".

Comment: Ok, so what doesn't work in this? I think you will have to show JS code.

Comment: I added it above.

Comment: Ok, so which one do you call to fill form values?

Comment: It's "MySuccessCallback"

Comment: What does `console.log(returnObject);` show you?

Comment: I should add that we run all this on a closed plattform ("JobRouter", that's why the JS commands have names with jr_* in front of it) and I don't know how to get console infos out of it...

Comment: you regex won't work, when the housenumber has an character like "a,b,c,d,e,f.." 
I would separate them into 2 fields, it's much easier to handle

Comment: @wolfus Check to see if any documentation can guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. After adding the code into the while-loop it worked perfectly:

```
      while ($row = $jobDB->fetchArray($result)) {            
          $street= $row[2];
          preg_match('/([^\d]+)(\d+.*)/', $street, $matches); 
          $street= trim($matches[1]);
          $house_number= trim($matches[2]);
            
          $this->setReturnValue('strasse', $street);
          $this->setReturnValue('hausnummer', $house_number);

        return;
    }
```

I'm not much of a developer, but maybe it was because the $row only works if called after the fetchArray. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. That's PHP 101. You can't read a variable before it's defined/created.

Comment: If you know, you know  And now I know.

Comment: I would recommend that you go through some "getting started with PHP" tutorials. Without the fundamentals, you're going to struggle.

Answer (score 0):

in case you need a function to do this you could use this:

```
/**
 * splits Number from street
 * 
 * @param string $strAndNumber 
 * @return array with 'street' and 'houseNumber'
 */
public static function splitStreetAndHousNumber($strAndNumber) {
    $pattern = '/^(.*?)\s*(\d+[a-zA-Z]{0,1})$/'; 
    if (preg_match($pattern, $strAndNumber, $matches)) {
        $street = trim($matches[1]);
        $houseNumber = trim($matches[2]);
        return array('street' => $street, 'houseNumber' => $houseNumber);
    } else {
        return array('street' => $strAndNumber, 'houseNumber' => '');
    }
}
```